# Redis consuming to much memory in magento2.4.3

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.4.3, redis, error-log

I have installed Redis for page cache and session storage here is the setting :

[image]
[image]
[image]

but it takes much memory and the website is slow also it gives the times a dataset is loading in memory error please guide me on how to setup Redis memory properly to make the store efficient and fast, I have more than 20000 products please guide me